# How to configure the Quarkus Mailer extension to allow dynamic 'from' email addresses based on user?

Tags: email, properties, configuration, quarkus

[This Quarkus mailer guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference) requires that the sending email is preconfigured in property file: `quarkus.mailer.from=YOUREMAIL@gmail.com`. However, my use case for email includes unique originator email based on user. Using the provided method looks something like:

```
public void sendEmail(EmailSender emailSender) {

    // Send to each recipient
    emailMessageRepository.findByEmailSenderId(emailSender.getId())
        .forEach(emailMessage ->
                mailer.send(
                    Mail.withText(emailMessage.getEmail(),
                    emailSender.getSubject(),
                    emailSender.getMessage())
            );
    );
}
```

How can I include the sender's email address (i.e. 'from') when the `Mail.withText()` method only provides for recipient email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documention showcases how to use multimailer (Multiple From Addresses)

```
quarkus.mailer.from=your-from-address@gmail.com 
quarkus.mailer.host=smtp.gmail.com

quarkus.mailer.aws.from=your-from-address@gmail.com 
quarkus.mailer.aws.host=${ses.smtp}
quarkus.mailer.aws.port=587

quarkus.mailer.sendgrid.from=your-from-address@gmail.com 
quarkus.mailer.sendgrid.host=${sendgrid.smtp-host}
quarkus.mailer.sendgrid.port=465
```

So you would write:

```
quarkus.mailer.from=default@gmail.com 

quarkus.mailer.aws.from=your_aws@gmail.com 

quarkus.mailer.sendgrid.from=your_sendgrid@gmail.com
```

Then you would inject them as shown below and use them based on whom you want to send with:

```
@Inject
@MailerName("aws") 
Mailer mailer;


@Inject
@MailerName("sendgrid") 
Mailer mailer;
```

**aws** and **sendgrid** at the names between `quarkus.mailer.xxx.from`

https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference#multiple-mailer-configurations

---

> The Quarkus Mailer is implemented on top of the Vert.x Mail Client,
> providing an asynchronous and non-blocking way to send emails.

If **you need fine control on how the mail is sent**, for instance if you need to retrieve the message ids, you can inject the underlying client, and use it directly:

```
@Inject MailClient client;
```

Then use it:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.setFrom("user@example.com (Example User)");
message.setTo("recipient@example.org");
message.setCc("Another User <another@example.net>");
message.setText("this is the plain message text");
message.setHtml("this is html text <a href=\"http://vertx.io\">vertx.io</a>");
```

To send using MailClient:

```
mailClient.sendMail(message)
  .onSuccess(System.out::println)
  .onFailure(Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference#using-the-underlying-vert-x-mail-client

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mail-client/java/